# Mysql workbench log file too large

Tags: mysql

i am  a novice with mysql workbench. i find every query i execute in the workbench will be logged in a file (C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\log\sql_actions_unconnected.log just like it).
i haved used the workbench for a long time (almost one year).the log file has grown up 5 GB. it is unbearable. the log is useless for me. i look around the menu bar.i haven't find any options to shut down this service.

so i want to consult about these questions 
1) is there a way to forbid mysql workbench not to log my query action. 
2) is there a way to make the workbench to only keep the log of last few days

my workbench version is (6.3.9 build 10690321 CE(64 bit))

Answer (score 2):

According to Workbench log documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-configuring-files.html#wb-configuring-files-log, everything is logged for debugging purposes. I regularly delete the file **sql_actions_unconnect.log** by accessing it right from within Workbench on the menu: Help > Locate Log Files.

I have not found a way of limiting the log size but also yet to experience any negative effects of this deletion on my environment. For now I'm just happy to get my 4GB space back!

Hope this helps.